# Is it possible to use "Agora Flat Open Source Virtual Classroom" within a Flutter application?

Tags: flutter, integration, agora.io

I am just wondering to know if it is possible to integrate [Agora Flat Open Source Virtual Classroom](https://flat.whiteboard.agora.io/en/) with Flutter? Is there any example/project doing this? Or is there something similar a virtual classroom written for Flutter?

Comment: Off-topic for this site.  Sorry

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible because agora has a web version for it's white board. so basically you can open it in flutter's webview.

it's not an exact solution but it will work.

Comment: Do you know if Agora's classroom works standalone or needs some API to work? I mean if someone wants to add this classroom to his website, should he buy some API services from Agora or it's completely free and open source?